Rasterize to numpy array
I am working on spatial data consisting of vectors containing polygons. In order to rasterize it I use a code similar to this:
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube

out_grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data = shapefile,    # shapefile is a geopandas.GeoDataFrame
    measurement = shapefile['NumValue'],
    resolution = (-1, 1),
    fill = 0
)
xar_grid = out_grid.NumValue 
np_grid = xar_grid.to_numpy()

But this process is too slow (I will have to repeat it multiple times). Is there a way to rasterize directly to numpy array from the shapefile ?
